# Django find oldest entry in database

Tags: python, django, datetime, view

Looking for a way in a Django view to find the oldest entry in the database. Then take that value and to a time since. There has to be a simple way to do this with writing a complicated query.

Comment: The entry with the oldest date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a created timestamp on your model, then could you sort ascending by this field and grab the first value?
To do the differences between the dates, you *may* be able to use an aggregate function to find the highest and lowest date, but I am uncertain. Something along the following lines might work:

`MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(lowest=Min('created_at'), highest=Max('created_at'))`

And then calculate the difference between those two - this all depending of course on Min and Max aggregate functions working correctly with dates...